# raspberry pi is missing the back slash on keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, raspberry-pi

I tried to change to us keyboard with sudo dpky or something.  I tried vi for lxde and keyboard went crazy. I tried using the chr(92) to replace the backslash(using ascii).  How do I get the keyboard to enter the backslash for when I need it in python idle.  (I use it alot)

Comment: The default keyboard setting is British, so the key mappings are a little different.

Answer (score 2):

Are the Keyboard Settings correct on the Raspberry Pi?  You could configure the Keyboard layout by running:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then setting the Keyboard layout to match the one specific to your keyboard.  I believe by Default it is set to English(UK).

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Needed to change keyboard to microsoft-got it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your pi!